# Check extension installed in TYPO3 v11 TypoScript Condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 before 8.7 it was common to use something like

```
[userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('felogin')]
```

to check whether the extension "felogin" is installed or not (example taken from the `css_styled_content` former system extension).

In TYPO3 v9.5, i think, the SEL (Symfony Expression Language) was introduced and in v10.4 became mandatory. In the documentation I see no way to express the aforementioned condition in SEL, except by creating a custom function.

Is a custom function really the only way? Do I have to implement 2 PHP classes (to get the custom function runnning) instead of that one line now? Or has the paradigm shifted so I should not need to check for installed extensions? What is the idea here?

Comment: In my opinion, the use case should be reviewed again. IMO it makes little sense to make settings in a concrete instance dependent on installed extensions - either they are required (and therefore present), or not. The conditions only make sense if this package/TypoScript is used in *different* projects.

Comment: That makes sense but my use case is not a concrete instance – I am literally using css_styled_content in v11 and want to upgrade the TS as it is there without altering its meaning. I would categorize your stance as "paradigm shifted", right? So css_styled_content has a `tt_content.login` part if `felogin` is installed (authored by the TYPO3 core team) – should I remove the condition so the TS applies unconditionally?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Actually, I just dug a little deeper into what css_styled_content does here specifically; I found that the whole part is obsolete for any TYPO3 ≥ 9.5. And I'm fine just removing the whole condition and its content. I would slightly tweak your comment to also address cases that are not concrete installations but generally this is evidence in your favor and I would say you can have the correct answer if you care to take the time to write it as such.

Comment: Yes, in ccs_styled_content, there were several "historical" parts or needs solved... There are different reasons why it was discontinued after TYPO3 v8 and you should take fluid_styled_content or adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes little sense to have settings in a concrete instance dependent on installed extensions - either they are required (and therefore present), or not.

The conditions only make sense if this package/TypoScript is used in different projects (like a general sitepackage in some agencies, or like bootstrap_package).

---

If you really *need* such a condition, you have to extend TYPO3 by a custom function, as you already wrote (-> [Extending the ExpressionLanguage in TYPO3](https://usetypo3.com/symfony-expression-language-in-typo3.html#c615)).